# Why I can't use vim after exit?

Tags: docker

I install `Kali Linux` using `docker`.
And, I tried install `vim` to `Kali Linux`.
I can use vim temporary. However, I can't use it after exit from docker.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share what kind of commands you are using for this. It's hard to guess what your problem is. Also share what the exact symptoms are for "I can't use it". That sentence can mean a lot of things.

Comment: OK, if you installed in on docker and you exit docker, where are you expecting it to run?

Comment: I used "docker run" command to use Kali linux, and used "apt-get install vim" to install vim. Then I could use vim. However, I can't use vim after use exit.

Comment: Once you exit a container, it's pretty much gone.  You rarely install software in running containers for exactly this reason.  Build a custom image, usually a containing a complete application, and run that.  The Docker documentation has a [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) running through the standard image build sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assuming what you mean is, you have installed `kali linux` using `docker` and then installed vim and everything is working fine. But after exiting from the container and when you re-run it for exampel,

`docker run kalilinux/kali-linux-docker /bin/bash`

Vim is not there? this because containers are volatile. If you wanna add vim permanently, add vim in the build time.

Dockerfile

```py
FROM kalilinux/kali-linux-docker

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```

Build the image

`docker build -t newkali .`

Verify,

`docker images`

Run

`docker run -it newkali /bin/bash`